# how to convert created new list of matched values from existing list using java stream

Tags: java, selenium, java-stream

Currently I used nested for-each loop to achieve the same.

```
List<String> valueListToBeFilter = Arrays.asList("8 digit mobile number", "Please enter mobile number.");
List<String> newfoundValueList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String value : valueListToBeFilter) {
    for (WebElement element : _webElementsErrorList) {
        if (element.getText().contains(value))
            newfoundValueList.add(element.getText());
    }
}
newfoundValueList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am getting the required result, but how to achieve the same using stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to swap `map` and `filter` in the "nested" stream to reduce the code a little bit more, but generally it's a minor improvement:

```java
List<String> newfoundValueList = valueListToBeFilter
    .stream()
    .flatMap(value -> _webElementsErrorList
        .stream()
        .map(WebElement::getText)
        .filter(elementText -> elementText.contains(value))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work with `.flatMap` and another stream of the `WebElement`-List like this:

```java
List<String> newfoundValueList = valueListToBeFilter.stream()
    .flatMap(value -> _webElementsErrorList.stream()
        .filter(element -> element.getText().contains(value))
        .map(element -> element.getText()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: can you please suggest tutorial which helps to learn stream and lambda?